# debug commands for formating drive

Tags: hard-drive, formatting

I want to delete all the data on my hard drive, including partitions.

What commands should I put in the command prompt for debugging the hard drive?

I do not have any OS on my laptop. how to do it?

any response is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all data (including partitions) on your disk by booting a bootable USB stick or CD with Knoppix and using the QTparted tool.